# How to dismiss all desired notifications on Android?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm creating a chat app that sends and receives notifications through Firebase Cloud Functions. Let's suppose I have 2 friends, and each friend sends me 5 messages(5 notifications). When I open a chat in my chat list, I want all notifications for that chat to be dismissed and the others not.

Currently I can only dimiss 1 notification. If I get more than one notification the `notificationManager.cancel(notificationId)` doesn't work. I don't want to use `notificationManager.cancelAll()` as I just want to dismiss some notifications.

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

    remoteMessage.notification.let { notification ->

        val type = remoteMessage.data[NOTIFICATION_TYPE]

        val notificationChannelId = getNotificationChannelId(type)
        val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        val notificationIntent = setIntent(remoteMessage.data)
        val stackBuilder: TaskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(HomeActivity::class.java)
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent)
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent)
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelId)
            .setContentTitle(notification?.title ?: "")
            .setContentText(notification?.body ?: "")
            .setStyle(
                NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(notification?.body ?: "")
            )
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorNotification))
            .setVibrate(vibrationPattern)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

        notify(remoteMessage.data, notificationManager, notificationBuilder)

    }
}

private fun notify(
    data: Map<String, String>,
    notificationManager: NotificationManager,
    notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder
) {

    when (data[NOTIFICATION_TYPE]) {
        CHAT_MSG -> {
            if (data[NotificationUtils.CHAT_ID] != ChatActivity.currentChat) {
                notificationManager.notify(
                    CHAT_MSG_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                    notificationBuilder.build()
                )
            }
        }
        FRIEND_REQUEST -> {
            notificationManager.notify(
                FRIEND_REQUEST_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                notificationBuilder.build()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

OnStart():

```
fun dismissNotifications(notificationId: Int) {
    val notificationManager =
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.cancel(notificationId)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts is:
Save all notificationIds in map where:
key is userName/userId in message.
value is List of notificationId

When you need to clear all notifications you just ask you map and clear all that notificationIds for that userName/userId